# Kivy: How to fix 'unable to create playbin' error in gstplayer

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm new to both kivy and python. for a project I want to create a desktop app with kivy that displays a video. when I run my code I get the error 'unable to create playbin'

Could someone help me out?

mainKivyApp.py

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout

class video_player(RelativeLayout):
    pass

class video(App):
    def build(self):
        return video_player()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    video().run()
```

video.kv

```
<video_player>:
    Video:
        source: "../example.mp4"
        play: True
```

kivy log:

```
[INFO   ] Kivy: v1.10.1
[INFO   ] Python: v3.6.8 (v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 02:04:31)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
[INFO   ] Factory: 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_sdl2, 
img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] Window: Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] GL: Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] GL: Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL version <b'2.1 INTEL-12.4.7'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Inc.'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) Iris(TM) Plus Graphics 640'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] GL: Shading version <b'1.20'>
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] Window: auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] Window: virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] VideoGstplayer: Using Gstreamer 1.10.4.0
[INFO   ] Video: Provider: gstplayer
[ERROR  ] Image: Error loading texture ../example.mp4
[INFO   ] Base: Start application main loop
[INFO   ] Base: Leaving application in progress...
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It's a issue in PyInstaller try to make:

> brew install gst-plugins-bad

Information from:

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4931

Comment: I've looked through the issue you've adressed and installed the gst-plugins-bad, but I'm still running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a different issue indeed. For me `brew install gst-plugins-bad` did not solve the issue for me either.

What did work was removing the 'gstplayer' in my kivy install. Where ever you kivy install is some where in 'site-packages/kivy/lib/gstplayer'
Do `rm -R site-packages/kivy/lib/gstplayer`
Again, this path should be replaced with your local installation path.

Based on the comments here in [this issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2381#issuecomment-445254454) on the kivy github site.
There the directory is called 'gstreamer'. In my installation it was called 'gstplayer'.

After removing that directory the video window shows up.